# What's the Apache OFbiz PHP or Python alternatives?

Tags: java, php, python

I'm looking for alternative solutions like OFbiz.  My main issue with OFbiz is that it has a long learning curve.  I hope to find a good alternative even written in another language like PHP or Python.

Comment: Can you provide more details?  Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! We will need much more information to give good recommendations here – asking for "a tool like X" is never giving enough details, even if linked. You should always list your requirements explicitly. Please see [How to ask for an alternative to some software](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/48/185) and the questions linked to it for details.

Answer (score 1):

After some good research i find mainly three good alternatives:

1-OpenBravo http://www.openbravo.com/

Python Based

2-Odoo (OpenErp) https://www.odoo.com/

Python Based

3-OpenTabs http://www.opentaps.org/

Is based on OFBiz (Java) with enhanced UI and more features.

Comment: Like your question, this answer is rather "low quality" according to our standards. We don't favour "lists" here (none of the SE sites does), but *full answers*, describing the recommended software: how it matches the requirements (you didn't specify), explaining what makes it a good match (and what might be "cons"), giving your own experiences. As it currently stands, not only is your question too broad – but so is your answer. Maybe you could fix that up? Thanks in advance! :)